# create new-spweb using given password and username in powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell

i want to create a new sub site using power shell but by a given user as in context, how can i do this.

I am using New-SPWeb Cmdlet.

Comment: Can you explain your objective and clarify your question a little further...

Answer (score 1):

You could try this... although I have to warn you I've never done it before.

```
$username = 'DOMAIN\username'
$password = 'Pa$$word'
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock 
{ 
#Your PS Code...
New-SPWeb -url "http://server" -Template "STS#0" -Name "test99" -Description "test99" -UseParentTopNav
}
```